# Places API by Google not loading suggestions

Tags: flutter, dart, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I have implemented a search for locations button in my maps page for a flutter app. I tried to use Places API from Google Cloud Platform and also used BloC through this youtube tutorial but I am not seeing any suggestions load at all even after the loading's CircularProgressIndicator goes away.

Search Code :

```
return BlocBuilder<AutoCompleteBloc, AutoCompleteState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AutoCompleteLoading) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (state is AutoCompleteLoaded) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 70.0, 10.0),
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search',
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.white70,
                contentPadding:
                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 5),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                context
                    .read<AutoCompleteBloc>()
                    .add(LoadAutoComplete(searchInput: value));
              },
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Text('Error');
        }
      },
    );
```

Map Screen Code:

```
Column(
          children: [
            SearchMap(),
            BlocBuilder<AutoCompleteBloc, AutoCompleteState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is AutoCompleteLoading) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (state is AutoCompleteLoaded) {
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 70),
                    height: 300,
                    color: state.autocomplete.length > 0
                        ? Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)
                        : Colors.transparent,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: state.autocomplete.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                              state.autocomplete[index].description,
                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .headline6!
                                  .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Text('Error');
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Bloc Code:

```
class AutoCompleteBloc extends Bloc<AutoCompleteEvent, AutoCompleteState> {
  final PlacesRepo _placesRepo;

  StreamSubscription? _placesSubscription;

  AutoCompleteBloc({required PlacesRepo placesRepo})
      : _placesRepo = placesRepo,
        super(AutoCompleteLoading());

  @override
  Stream<AutoCompleteState> mapEventToState(
    AutoCompleteEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is LoadAutoComplete) {
      yield* _mapLoadAutoCompleteToState(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<AutoCompleteState> _mapLoadAutoCompleteToState(
      LoadAutoComplete event) async* {
    _placesSubscription?.cancel();

    final List<PlacesAutoComplete> autocomplete =
        await _placesRepo.getAutoComplete(event.searchInput);

    yield AutoCompleteLoaded(autocomplete: autocomplete);
  }
}
```

Autocomplete State & Autocomplete Event Code :

```
abstract class AutoCompleteState extends Equatable {
  const AutoCompleteState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class AutoCompleteLoading extends AutoCompleteState {}

class AutoCompleteLoaded extends AutoCompleteState {
  final List<PlacesAutoComplete> autocomplete;

  const AutoCompleteLoaded({required this.autocomplete});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [autocomplete];
}

class AutoCompleteError extends AutoCompleteState {}

--

abstract class AutoCompleteEvent extends Equatable {
  const AutoCompleteEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadAutoComplete extends AutoCompleteEvent {
  final String searchInput;

  LoadAutoComplete({this.searchInput = ''});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [searchInput];
}
```

Does there need to be a billing/payment in order to use this feature?

Comment: yes. you need to enable billing to get the key for places api suggestions

Comment: You need you need a project with a billing account and the Places API enabled https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview